# Why when moving objects forward they are moving very slow ? How can i change the speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In `Update` function:
The `UpdateSpheres` create the objects and then move them, but they are moving very slow.

```
private void Update()
{
    UpdateSpheres();
    MoveShips();
}

private void MoveShips()
{
    var spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");
    foreach (Transform child in spheres[0].transform) 
    {
        child.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `FindGameObjectsWithTag` in every frame is very slow. Call that once in the `Start` function. Also add a public speed variable you can use to multiple to change the speed. You can modify this speed variable from the Editor until you get the speed you want. Make sure to look in the rest of your script and make sure that you are not using `GameObject.Find`, `FindGameObjectsWithTag` or similar functions in the `Update` function.

```
GameObject[] spheres;
public float moveSpeed = 50;

void Start()
{
    spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");
}

private void Update()
{
    UpdateSpheres();
    MoveShips();
}

private void MoveShips()
{
    foreach (Transform child in spheres[0].transform)
    {
        child.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```